# eval and extract field with pd.series for multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have a bunch of json-ish strings stored in columns as shown in 'a', and I would like to extract the 'Form' field. I would like to do this per row, for all columns. I can get it to work per cell with the code below, but I am having trouble getting it to work on a dataframe scale. any advice is welcomed

```
# dataframe
a = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': ["{'Test': 'active', 'Form': 'k9lo'}", "{'Test': 'active', 'Form': 'jhy9'}"],
                       'col2': ["{'Test': 'deactive', 'Form': 'nyt7'}", "{'Test': 'deactive', 'Form': 'ha37'}"]})
a = a.set_index([pd.Index([3, 5])])

# code that works for one cell
import ast
ast.literal_eval(a.col1.apply(pd.Series)[0][3])['Form']

# expected output 
b = pd.DataFrame(data={'Form1': ['k9lo', 'jhy9'],
                       'Form2': ['nyt7','ha37']})
```

Thank you for looking, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for processing per columns, then convert each values to dictionary and select by [`Series.str.get`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html), last `rename` columns:

```
f = lambda x: x.apply(ast.literal_eval).str.get('Form')
a = a.apply(f).rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('col','Form'))
print (a)
  Form1 Form2
3  k9lo  nyt7
5  jhy9  ha37
```